# select method on array providing different results

Tags: arrays, ruby

The following are identical:

**First method:**

```
puts [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6].select {|number| number == 6 }
```

Output:

```
6
6
6
6
```

**Second method:**

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6]
array.select do |number|
  puts number == 6
end
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
```

Why don't I get the same result for each? How do I go about getting the same result? Please explain what is going on.

Comment: The difference is that you are using `puts` in 2nd method. just remove it.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Described in the [ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select),

> select → an_enumerator
>
> Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which the given
> block returns a true value.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6].select {|number| number == 6 }
```

returns as intended (i.e, return an `array` where the `number == 6`)

```
[6, 6, 6, 6]
```

In the second method, you're simply outputting the result of the comparison, which will result in a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

- Regarding the output, the first method `puts` the selected array whereas the second method `puts` each evaluation of the condition (regardless of whether the condition is met).
- Regarding the selected array, the block in the first method returns the evaluation of `number == 6`, which leads to the selected array `[6, 6, 6, 6]`, whereas the block in the second method returns the evaluation of `puts`, which is `nil`, which leads to the selected array `[]`.
- Regarding the return value of the entire code, the first method returns the evaluation of `puts`, which is `nil`, whereas the second method returns the selected array `[]`.